# ¿Cómo obtener el path?

Tags: laravel-5

Envío a un `helper` el directorio de la siguiente forma:

```
$dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$event->code));
```

Luego recibo los datos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo lograr es obtener la `url` del `path`, no sé como hacerlo, para poder leerlo con:

```
is_dir($dir)
```

Pero al parecer solo lee las rutas tipo: /images/events/etc...

No puedo pasarla de esa manera `($dir = '/images/events/'.$event->code)` ya que el directorio del virtual `host` está apuntando al directorio `public` del proyecto `laravel`, y si lo hago de esa manera no encuentra la ruta.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer o con qué fin? a ver si podemos orientar el problema de otra forma

Comment: Hola, ya te explico, por ahora encontré que puedo acceder al path de la siguiente forma: $dir->path y obtengo solo la ruta del objeto... Intento y comento.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien pero:

**Si lo que necesitás es obtener la ruta donde está almacenado el archivo podés usar el helper [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path)**

```
$path = public_path('images/events/'.$event->code);
// C:/xampp/htdocs/public/images/events/123456
```

**Si lo que querés es obtener la url del archivo podés usar el helper [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset)**

```
$url = asset('images/events/'.$event->code);
// http://tusitio.com/images/events/123456
```

Comment: Disculpa, el problema de esa ruta es que no encuentra la imágenes, ya que laravel usa el directorio public/ y $url = asset('images/events/'.$event->code); no las encuentra

Comment: la carpeta imagenes esta en el mismo nivel de public?

Comment: Está dentro del public

Comment: Que raro, intentaste por las dudas y **solo a modo de prueba** poner `asset('public/images/events/'.$event->code);`  o `public_path('public/images/events/'.$event->code);`  o incluso `url('public/images/events/'.$event->code);` ¿Qué es exactamente lo que necesitás? el path o la url?